# Symfony route collision with folder in /web

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, routes

So, when defining a route in symfony (3) like this:

```
app:
  path: /app
  defaults:
    _controller: WebsiteBundle:App:index
```

And there happens to be a folder named `app` (containing assets like JS, images, etc.) inside your `web` folder this route stops working in a production environment. It just redirects to /web/app/ and then throws a 404. When serving through the console on localhost this works fine since all routing happens in PHP by magix, but when using apache this seems to go wrong.

I think these two lines /web/.htaccess are breaking everything, but I'm not sure. I'm not a master of .htaccess and I always copy-paste the magic I find online (or provided by the default symfony build).

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this particular case I could solve it by just running the /app route on / instead, but for future reference an answer to this riddle might come in handy.

Thanks in advance, y'all crazy smart people out there.

**[UPDATE]**

This is the full .htaccess file in the apache root directory:

```
#php_value memory_limit 512M
#php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
#php_value post_max_size 20M

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Force HTTPS
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Rewrite all queries to the web directory.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}web/$1 [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.woff\.gz$ - [T=application/x-font-woff,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding

    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and this is the full .htaccess file in the symfony web folder:
    # Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
    # every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
    # mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
    # start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
    # to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
    DirectoryIndex app.php

```
# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello, the issue indeed in `.htaccess` rules, but not in these lines of code. Insert full htaccess source code.

Comment: Smart, I added the complete htaccess files (in the first one there was a "mod_expires" section, but I left that out since this only modifies the headers).

Comment: What do you mean by `this route stops working in a production env`. Does it redirect to `/web/app/` directory when you call `/app`?

Comment: Indeed it does. Apparently I forgot a lot of specifics in this one, sorry.